# How to add a custom function to smarty extension yii2

Tags: php, yii2, smarty

i have a little problem with smarty extension for yii2.

I've created a new smarty function, and i've added the code into this file:

> backend/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-smarty/src/Extension.php

```
 public function __construct($viewRenderer, $smarty)
    {
        //other code
        /* CUSTOM FUNCTION REGISTER */
        $smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'test', [$this, 'functionTest']);
    }
//this is the custom function
public function functionTest($params, $template){
        return "Test custom funcion";
    }
```

And i can use this custom function into my template like this `{test}` and all works fine.

Today i have update the yii2 to the 2.0.20 version, and obviously the Extension.php file was replaced, so i can't access anymore to the custom function.
My question is: How i can add a custom function for smarty in yii2?

I'll set the config array in this way:

```
//this is in backend/config/main.php
'view' => [

            'renderers' => [
                'tpl' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\smarty\ViewRenderer',
                    'pluginDirs' => ['@backend/saSmartyPlugin'],
                    'widgets' =>[
                                  'functions' => [['test' => 'test'], ],
                                ],
                    //'cachePath' => '@runtime/Smarty/cache',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

and the into saSmartyPlugin folder i insert my `test.php` file like this:

```
<?php
    class Test{
        function functionTest($params, $template){
           return "Test custom funcion";
        }
    }
```

But i get this error:

> Smarty: Undefined class 'test' in register template class

[image]

Comment: you dont modify source files but you extend the desired class to add your modification but before you do that you should have a string reason to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll find a solution thinking about @MuhammadOmerAslam and @SergheiLeonenco suggest me.
I write this answer for anyone who has this problem.

First i create my php file Test.php and i extend the Extension class of Smarty

```
namespace common\components;

use yii\smarty\Extension;

class Test extends Extension{

    public function __construct($viewRenderer, $smarty){ 

        parent::__construct($viewRenderer, $smarty);// call parent construct
        $smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'bread', [$this, 'functionBreadcrumbs']);//register my custom function
    }
    //My custom function
    function functionTest($params, $template){
       return "Test custom funcion";
    }
```

And i save this file into `common/components/`

After that i have modified my config.php file

```
'view' => [

            'renderers' => [
                'tpl' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\smarty\ViewRenderer',
                    'extensionClass' => 'common\components\Test'
                ],
            ],
        ],

    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Muhammad Omer Aslam, you should extend from backend/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-smarty/src/Extension.php in order to create Any new methods and be able to use them after update. After that you just write in your config file path to your extended class.

Comment: Tried but not working. For me it's not clear how to do it and where to put the file. I didn't find any tutorial.

Comment: First of all you have to understand the basic concepts of creating new component:

[link]https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0[/link]

after that If you have a custom component, not your's, you have to look at Docs or review files and see how you can extend them.